# How to refresh a view in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, view, refresh, reset

In my android application, in a view, there are RadioButton view, TextView, Checkbox view, date picker, clock picker and so on.

at the bottom, there are two button. One of them is add and the other one is reset. I want that when the user click to reset, that should naturally refresh the whole view and all values in childview should be set to the default value. How can I achieve that ?

Thank you very much for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way but I think it should do the job for simple cases:-

Restart your activity without animation.

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Comment: its bad way to better to recreate view.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup myViewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.myId);
   myViewGroup.removeAllViews();
   myViewGroup.refreshDrawableState();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I applied your code but in this case, all childviews in the view disappears. I just want to set all of them to the their default values.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)